# Adding Add Item(s) functionality in Opportunity

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to add  Add Items functionality in Opportunity like in Sales Order. I have gone through the code in SOOrderEntry and I have tried to replicate the same functionality.

The Add Item menu brings the smart panel with filter options, but it does not populate the data. I have compared the setting with Sales Order Add Item Smart panel settings and I did not miss anything.

I have replicated the table structure and events as in sales order with changes required for Opportunity.

```
#region SiteStatus Lookup
public PXFilter<OpportunitySiteStatusFilter> oppsitestatusfilter;
[PXFilterable]
[PXCopyPasteHiddenView]
public OpportunityStatusLookup<OpportunitySiteStatusSelected, OpportunitySiteStatusFilter> opportunitysitestatus;

public PXAction<CROpportunity> addOppBySite;
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Add Stock Item", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
[PXLookupButton]
public virtual IEnumerable AddOppBySite(PXAdapter adapter)
{
    oppsitestatusfilter.Cache.Clear();
    if (opportunitysitestatus.AskExt() == WebDialogResult.OK)
    {
        return AddOppSelBySite(adapter);
    }
    oppsitestatusfilter.Cache.Clear();
    opportunitysitestatus.Cache.Clear();
    return adapter.Get();
}

public PXAction<CROpportunity> addOppSelBySite;
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Add", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select, Visible = false)]
[PXLookupButton]
public virtual IEnumerable AddOppSelBySite(PXAdapter adapter)
{
    foreach (OpportunitySiteStatusSelected line in opportunitysitestatus.Cache.Cached)
    {
        if (line.Selected == true && line.QtySelected > 0)
        {
            CROpportunityProducts newline = PXCache<CROpportunityProducts>.CreateCopy(Base.Products.Insert(new CROpportunityProducts()));
            newline.SiteID = line.SiteID;
            newline.InventoryID = line.InventoryID;
            newline.SubItemID = line.SubItemID;
            newline.UOM = line.SalesUnit;
            //newline.AlternateID = line.AlternateID;
            //newline = PXCache<SOLine>.CreateCopy(Transactions.Update(newline));
            //if (newline.RequireLocation != true || PXAccess.FeatureInstalled<FeaturesSet.warehouseLocation>())
            //    newline.LocationID = null;
            newline = PXCache<CROpportunityProducts>.CreateCopy(Base.Products.Update(newline));
            //newline.Qty = line.QtySelected;
            cnt = 0;
            Base.Products.Update(newline);
        }
    }
    opportunitysitestatus.Cache.Clear();
    return adapter.Get();
}
protected virtual void OpportunitySiteStatusFilter_RowInserted(PXCache cache, PXRowInsertedEventArgs e)
{
    OpportunitySiteStatusFilter row = (OpportunitySiteStatusFilter)e.Row;
    if (row != null && Base.Products.Current != null)
        row.SiteID = Base.Products.Current.SiteID;
}
int cnt;
public IEnumerable<PXDataRecord> ProviderSelect(BqlCommand command, int topCount, params PXDataValue[] pars)
{
    cnt++;
    return Base.ProviderSelect(command, topCount, pars);
}
#endregion
```

[image]

Regards,
R. Muralidharan

Comment: Are you sure that when you debug the code the data is being populated to the corresponding cache of the datamember you defined for the grid?
If yes the problem here will be the autosize of the grid. Make autosize of the grid to true so that you can see the data inside.

Comment: You may want to compare your custom SmartPanel aspx with out-of-box Add Stock Item SmartPanel of SalesOrderEntry screen. As @Hybridzz mentioned, most likely you haven’t set AutoSize property. You need to set AutoSize to True when Grid pagination is Enabled. 

If this does not help then we would need to review declaration of DAC, Graph and ASPX.

Comment: Setting Autosize property for the grid solved the issue. I have fixed other filtering issue and it is working fine. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to compare your custom SmartPanel aspx with out-of-box Add Stock Item SmartPanel of SalesOrderEntry screen. As @Hybridzz mentioned, most likely you haven’t set AutoSize property. You need to set AutoSize to True when Grid pagination is Enabled.